# What is the optimal way to share code between Activities with different base classes?

Tags: java, android

I have the following problem:
I have an abstract *Activity* class, lets call it *MyAbstractActivity*, that contains some code I'd like to reuse (for example: a standard service binder, common menu items, common initialization code, etc. etc.). Normally I would just use it to subclass my concrete activities and be done with it.

However, I occasionally need to use another supertype, such as a *ListActivity* or a *MapActivity*.

### So the question is: how do I avoid duplicating that support code within an Activity, if I have to use another base class?

I have thought up of a solution based on the decorator pattern, like this one:
[image: Activity Decorator]
.

However, I see a problem with this approach: 
What to do with protected methods (like *onCreate()*)? Should I introduce an additional "bridge" class that makes them public for the purpose of the decorator, similarly to the way presented below (starting to look a bit byzantine...)?

[image: edge case]

Any other way?

I hope I made myself relatively clear. Thanks in advance for any feedback!

PS. Using static utility classes is not a good solution in my opinion, since it introduces a possibility of hard-to-identify programming bugs.

Comment: Sorry for not actually embedding the diagram, it wouldn't let me :p.

Comment: i say create some static methods somewhere and keep your `MyAbstractActivity` initialization bound to these static methods.  I'm currently doing this with my applications.  I have tons of activities which are children of a parent activity. i pass around a lot of intent extras to keep track of what activity i'm on

Comment: OK, but the problem is I cannot directly subclass MyAbstractActivity in this case, because I need to subclass MapActivity.

Comment: this is why you have those public static methods which you can access in this other parent activity.  you'll need 2 "abstract" activities, 1 for regular type activities and another for activities including maps.  each of these activities will initialize themselves through these static methods, eliminating as much redundancy as possible

Comment: Oh, OK - I thought you misunderstood me, sorry. Do I understand correctly that you mean calling those static methods in onCreate() etc.? In this case, I'm afraid my PS applies. I would really like something with less risk of introducing a bug.

Comment: perhaps use a class which extends `Application`. retrieve the class in each base activity and use its methods. this also has its drawbacks since you can't guarantee that the this class extending `Application` will have data saved or not(due to Android killing your application, values being destroyed, etc).

Comment: That would be the same problem as moving the specific functionality to Fragments and keeping the common code in the Activity - you lose the intended modularity. Additionally, this is not about the data, but also about some Activity-specific issues (standard dialogs for example).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, neither Fragments nor the Decorator Pattern are clean or appropriate solutions for what you want to accomplish.  They were designed to solve other problems.

I find myself moving "support" code, or "framework" code, or "all that verbose, repetitive, boilerplate crap" to static utility methods.  This isn't necessarily the approach I'd take on a non-Android project, but in my Android projects, it works pretty darn well.

Also, know that you don't need to subclass ListActivity to have a ListView.

Comment: Hmm... for me the problem with using static utility classes in an Android Activity context is this: you have to remember where and in which hooks you should place what calls, i.e. "this goes to onCreate(), this goes to onPause() etc.". For me, it really minimizes the benefit of code reuse and increases the risk for bugs. I know that you can have a ListView without a ListActivity, but it was only one example. I realize the risks with using decorators in such a case, but I believe that in my development case the side-effects will not override the benefits. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: Although it is not explicit in your answer, it got me thinking that using Fragments in this case is not really the way forward - Fragments should be, I quote, "a modular and reusable component". Making a Fragment dependent on a specific Activity class would defeat that purpose. I'll edit my question accordingly and upvote your answer (that is, if I can do the latter :) ). Thanks again.